# Generalising Grid Engine qsub job file for multiple programs and input file names

Tags: bash, scripting, cluster, gridengine

I am using Grid Engine on a Linux cluster. I am running many jobs with different programs and different input files. I don't want to create multiple specific job scripts for each pair of program and input file. Instead I want to be able to specify the program name and the input file on the `qsub` line.

Therefore I can use `qsub job.sh <programNameAndLocation> <inputFileName>`

Where `job.sh` takes two arguments. This works fine. But there is another twist: my programs are located in a very very long directory which I don't want to type every time I submit a job - so aliases are an obvious choice.

So I want to do something like `qsub job.sh <programNameAndLocationAlias> <inputFileName>`

I initially set the alias in my `.bashrc` but was getting the error: `<programNameAndLocationAlias>: command not found`

So I set the alias in `submit.sh`. But I am getting the same error.

Thoughts on how can I can get the command `qsub job.sh $1 $2` to accept aliases also?

Comment: What shell are you using? (this is probably better solved by a function that does a lookup, not an alias)

Comment: I'm using bash (tag added). I should be looking in to indirect referencing a la `${!<programNameAndLocation>}` then?

Comment: I have tried using indirect expansion so my input line becomes `qsub job.sh ${!<programNameAndLocationParameter>} <inputFileName>`. I am setting my parameter in my `.bashrc` via `export <programNameAndLocationParameter>=<programNameAndLocation>`. Now however I am getting an error which is telling me that bash is trying to execute my input file and it is not being read by my program. Any thoughts?

Comment: Okay, but what is `programNameAndLocationParameter`? A path? Two or more arguments?

Comment: `<programNameAndLocationParameter>` is a path and program name. e.g. `/exports/programs/solver` where "solver" is my program to be executed. The executed program itself accepts one argument. Which is the input file path and name (`<inputFilName>`).

Answer (score 0):

A hash and a lookup function might look something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A proggies

# "aliases" and then the path said should expand to
proggies[foo]=/some/big/long/stupid/path/foo
proggies[bar]=/some/big/long/stupid/path/bar

function qrunner {
    local exe
    exe=${proggies[$1]}
    if [[ -z "$exe" ]]; then
        echo >&2 "no mapping for '$1'"
        return 1
    fi
    # echo here is for debugging, remove when ready to
    # really break things
    echo qsub job.sh "$exe" "$2"
}

# positive test
qrunner bar filename
echo $?

# and also a negative one
qrunner nope filename
echo $?
```